# Create diff patches in java

Tags: java, diff, patch

honorable developers!
 Could you say, is there exist a java-library, that allow to create diff-patches, preferably from jar-files and apply them to those jar-files?
Maybe, somebody has an article about it?
I'll be very gratefull for your help.

Comment: I assume you mean unsigned JARs with compiled bytecode. As they contain non-plaintext files (aside from manifest and certain other descriptors), what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to create comfortable and quick mechanism for updating of jar-libraries.